# HTML Input Camera image out of focus on iPhone Video

Tags: input, webrtc, getusermedia, html-input, input-type-file

My website lets a user record and upload a file using some basic html

```
<input type="file" accept="video/*;capture=camcorder">
```

Everything works fine; however, I have noticed my video is blurry compared to when I'm just normally recording a video on my iPhone. I've tested on multiple devices and all are blurry. The problem is when using this input element the camera is blurry. Why would the input element make the camera blurry, compared to when I just used the iPhone camera app? Can I add some attributes to the html element? Do I need to specify size? etc.

Here is the difference on my phone. Here is a screenshot when using html input (and yes I tried clicking to focus): 
[image]

And here is screenshot from normal iPhone camera roll (when not opened through web input):
[image]

How can I make this input element camera look as good as the normal iPhone camera app?

Comment: Mobile cameras have autofocus. It takes time to operate, and until it locks on to an object or person the image will be out of focus. To make it work you should run the video camera for a few seconds, then capture an image. This might help you. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Taking_still_photos

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like this is not a true webrtc issue since it's only using the native file/camera system for IOS. I let the camera pause to find focus, but it never happened. The crazy thing is the image is fine on the normal iPhone app, but blurry on web. I even tested on Facebook mobile site and same effect. Suprised this hasn't been documented.

Comment: I didn't say it was a webrtc issue. I said you need to let the camera run (not paused) for a while before taking a picture. My webrtc link is a way to do that. There may be others.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I let the camera run (just left it open) for a few minutes and the focus stayed blurry; it's just not as crisp as the iPhone camera app. I looked at your link but don't see how it's relevant when just using the input type="file" to record vid. Does your link let you alter the camera when using <input type="file" ?

Comment: in what browser was that? Might be worth filing a bug.

Comment: It's weird the camera focuses fine when taking a picture, but it can't find focus when recording a video